# SPARQL: BIND of same variable outside and inside a group

Tags: sparql, arq

Is the use of `BIND` valid?

```
# Query 1
SELECT * {
  BIND (<http://ex/p2> as ?p)
  {
    BIND (<http://ex/p1> as ?p)
    ?s ?p ?o
  }
}
```

When run on turtle data:

```
@prefix h: <http://ex/> .
h:s1 h:p1 h:o1 .
h:s2 h:p2 h:o2 .
```

[arq 3.11.0](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/cmds.html) gives as result:

```
-------------
| p | s | o |
=============
-------------
```

without throwing an error (not even when using `--strict`).
But removing the group or changing the order does give an error:

```
# Query 2
SELECT * {
  BIND (<http://ex/p2> as ?p)
  BIND (<http://ex/p1> as ?p)
  ?s ?p ?o
}

BIND: Variable used when already in-scope: ?p in BIND(<http://ex/p1> AS ?p)
```

and:

```
# Query 3
SELECT * {
  {
    BIND (<http://ex/p1> as ?p)
    ?s ?p ?o
  }
  BIND (<http://ex/p2> as ?p)
}

BIND: Variable used when already in-scope: ?p in BIND(<http://ex/p2> AS ?p)
```

Questions:

1. Does Query 1 violate [10.1 BIND](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#bind) which states:

   > The variable introduced by the BIND clause must not have been used in
   >   the group graph pattern up to the point of use in BIND.
2. My reading of [18.2.1 Variable Scope](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#variableScope)
   is that in Query 1, the variable `?p` is in-scope *inside*
   the inner group and therefore also in-scope *outside* the group.
   Would the arq error message for Query 2 also be applicable to the
   Query 1?

I would be grateful for a clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, Query 1 does not violate the rules for `BIND`, and the query is valid. That is because query evaluation of groups in SPARQL is defined inside-out. Inner groups are evaluated separately, and before outer groups. If the inner group is taken on its own, the use of `BIND` in it is obviously fine, because `?p` has not yet been bound in the group. In the spec text you quote, the two key parts are: “must not have been used … **in the group graph pattern** … **up to the point** of use in BIND.”
2. In-scope variables need to be determined for each clause in a group separately, or in other words, at different places in a group, different variables are in scope. For the outer group in Query 1, before the `BIND`, no variables are in scope, and hence the `BIND` is valid. After the `BIND`, `?p` is in scope, which is why a second `BIND` gives an error in Query 2. One way to think about this: A group starts with an empty scope, and each clause may contribute variables to the group. If a variable has already been contributed by a preceding clause, `BIND` may not assign that variable.

Comment: I didn't know that the order of `BIND` matters but it looks like it's indeed the case given that's the only difference between query 1 and query 3. Funny to see this, should keep it in mind - thanks for clarification

Comment: Yes, with BIND, OPTIONAL and MINUS, the order matters.

Comment: yeah, with `OPTIONAL` and `MINUS` I knew already, with `BIND` I had no problems so far or better said, I used it never with same variable names etc. - but honestly didn't think about the order. Nice to know. But, not sure whether this is intuitive for all people. Sure, the same holds for `OPTIONAL` I guess, when not thinking of a left-join. So one more time that I learned it's worth reading specs of a formal language carefully